# Where do I edit the content of <article> of the "sticky post" - featured content

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

(Twentyfourteen theme)

I want to edit the  HTML content inside the "sticky post" - featured content.

I'm digging the wordpress files for an hour and just can't find the correct file.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

Click on "Appearance," and then click on "Editor" in the WordPress dashboard.
**Step 2**

Locate the file that displays tags. Most often, tags are found in the "single.php" file, but they may also be in the "index.html" file. Locate the right file by performing a text search in each file for the word "tag."

**Step 3**

Identify the function displaying the tags. This function can vary, and can be either be the "the_tags()," function, the "get_the_tags()" function or the "get_the_tags_list()" function. It will only be one of these -- you won't see more than one in the same file.
**Step 4**

Insert the following conditional code in the line before the tag function:
Step 5

Add the following code after the function:
}?>
**Step 6**

Click the "Update File" button to save the changes. This makes WordPress run the tag function only if the post is not a sticky post.

Comment: funny I found it :) 
under my nose whole the time